# How to get filename from a python logger

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have the following code

```
job_logger = logging.getLogger("abc")
job_handler = logging.FileHandler(filename)
job_logger.addHandler(job_handler)
print job_logger.something
```

I want to know the filename from the job_logger object. Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Assuming the `job_logger` object has only one handler for now.

```
>>> handler = job_logger.handlers[0]
>>> filename = handler.baseFilename
>>> print(filename)
'/tmp/test_logging_file'
```

And when there're multiple handlers, design your logic to get them all or get the very last one.

Comment: thanks for that!
think this will be the only of identifying it then

Comment: @hyades My pleasure to help.

Comment: This didn't work for me in the different context of my program. What did work was: my_logger.root.handlers[0].baseFilename

Comment: Error : module 'logging' has no attribute 'handlers'

Comment: @FernandoV You first need to create your logger instance "root = logging.getLogger()", then you can access the handlers list from the instance directly: "root.handlers".

Answer (score 4):

You can get a list of the handlers used in a logger using:

```
>>>handlers = job_logger.handlers
>>>handlers
[<FileHandler ./mypath/job_logger.log (NOTSET)>]
```

As in your case you only have one, @starrify solution should be enough:

```
>>>handlers[0].baseFilename
'./mypath/job_logger.log'
```

In case you have more handlers and some are not FileHandlers you can filter them with a list comprehension:

```
>>> log_paths = [handler.baseFilename for handler in job_logger.handlers if isinstance(handler, logging.FileHandler)]
>>> next(iter(log_paths))
'./mypath/job_logger.log'
```

Answer (score 1):

a comment rather, but with code formatting
baseFilename exists only in FileHandler subclass, thus

```
for handler in job_logger.handlers:
    if hasattr(handler, "baseFilename"):
        print(f"writing log to {getattr(handler, 'baseFilename')}")
```